# fgrep Match string patterns with a file

Tags: macos, grep

I used `fgrep -f`  to extract lines from `genedictionary.txt` which match  patterns (Ids) from pattern file (id.txt)

My command `fgrep -f id.txt genedictionary.txt > result.txt` is not giving any results.

How to modify this command to get the result as I want

My pattern file(id.txt) looks like (one Id in each line)

```
P04083 
P50995
Q9UJ72
P13747
A23444
```

My other file against which I should match these patterns looks like

```
ANXA1_HUMAN@SWISSPROT|P04083@SWISSPROT|ANXA1:ANXA1|
ANX10_HUMAN@SWISSPROT|Q9UJ72@SWISSPROT|ANXA10:ANXA10|
ANX11_HUMAN@SWISSPROT|P50995@SWISSPROT|ANXA11:ANXA11|
ANX13_HUMAN@SWISSPROT|P27216@SWISSPROT|ANXA13:ANXA13|
HLF_HUMAN@SWISSPROT|Q16534@SWISSPROT|HLF:HLF|
```

Output should be

```
ANXA1_HUMAN@SWISSPROT|P04083@SWISSPROT|ANXA1:ANXA1|
ANX10_HUMAN@SWISSPROT|Q9UJ72@SWISSPROT|ANXA10:ANXA10|
ANX11_HUMAN@SWISSPROT|P50995@SWISSPROT|ANXA11:ANXA11
```

Comment: you should make sure that in your id.txt there is no leading/trailing spaces. if you used `fgrep`. e.g. there is one trailing space after your `P04083 ` in your example.

Comment: Yes I removed. it worked Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first pattern `P04083` has a space at the end, so it doesn't match anything in `genedictionary.txt`.